# Youtube + Selenium ChromeDriver (Python) - How to loop youtube video?

Tags: python, selenium, loops

Already searched related questions but can't get solution.

How to use Python Selenium ChromeDriver to loop Youtube video?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It MIGHT be useful for your purposes since it's not quite clear.

Once the video starts playing, right-click on the video screen and selects the option `Loop`.

As follows:
https://giphy.com/gifs/xUSGPLMaJQaEnkcwTR/html5

However, it may be not enough because after the video repeats itself for a while (approximately 20x) it just goes to the next video.

A workaround is to use javascript in the browser itself.

After click on `Loop`, open chrome dev tools console and type the following into it:

```js
document.getElementById("loop").nextSibling.__shady_native_nextSibling.childElementCount = 2
```

The value here is arbitrarily and I cannot explain why, I only know that it should be greater than 1.

Doing so, the video should repeat itself indeterminately.